# Where to ask this question

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder when and how a context switch was first introduced. Is that welcome to ask or is there some better place to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems with such a question.  Given that we already have a number of questions regarding the history of software development and techniques, this should be fine.

As always, you should be quite specific about what you are after, to avoid the risk of being voted *too broad*.